# LiveConnectClient | DownloadAsync crashes without an exception

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, async-await, live-sdk

WP8, VS 2013
Live SDK (nuget) v5.5

```
private async void DownLoadImageFromSkyDrive(string imgUrl, Int32 number)
{
    LiveConnectClient client = new LiveConnectClient(_currentSession);
    var image = await client.DownloadAsync(imgUrl + "/content");
    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    bitmap.SetSource(image.Stream);
}
```

After the execution of

```
var image = await client.DownloadAsync(imgUrl + "/content");
```

The callstack is in the parent function. There's no exception, but

```
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
```

is not executed.
The code has worked....

Comment: MSDN has guidance for `async` methods called the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx). To summarize, you should make your method `async Task` instead of `async void`, name it `DownloadImageFromSkyDriveAsync`, and `await` the returned task from the calling method ("parent function").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or not yet executed... You function is an `async` method with no return value. It doesn't block the caller. Also I believe `async void` won't pass the exception to the caller. Put the `try catch` block in `DownLoadImageFromSkyDrive` to see what's going on.

Comment: It's indeed not yet executed!